# Timestamp en milisegundos python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

¿Existe alguna funcion o libreria para convertir fechas a timestamp con milisegundos?

Por ejemplo el timestamp 1577844540000 es igual a 01/01/2020 2:09:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objeto `datetime` tiene el método `fromtimestamp()`, que espera el parámetro en segundos. Basta que dividas por 1000 tu número:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.fromtimestamp(1577844540000//1000)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 2, 9)
>>> str(d)
'2020-01-01 02:09:00'
```

Si lo que necesitas es la conversión contraria, el objeto `datetime` también tiene un método `timestamp()` que te devuelve el resultado en segundos, así que en este caso bastará multiplicar por 1000:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 2, 9, 0)
# O también
>>> d = datetime.strptime('2020-01-01 02:09:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> d.timestamp()*1000
1577844540000.0
```